# How to get seaborn or matplotlib bar plots to flip direction of bars at 1 instead of the origin 0?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

In the data I'm working with, it's more valuable to see what values are greater than or less than one, and I want to show this with bars that go in opposite directions. This happens naturally for values greater than or equal to zero. How do I change this?

So far I have visual solution, but the axis values then aren't correct.

```
plt.barh(weights_df['Variable'],weights_df['Odds Ratio']-1, color="Purple", align='edge', label='Odds Ratio')
plt.xlabel('Odds Ratio')
plt.ylabel('Variable')
plt.title("Odds Ratios")
plt.show()
```

Sample data:
weights = {
'Age': 0.42,
'Location': 1.5,
'Smoke': 2.9,
'Lesion': 0.22,
}

Comment: Sample data would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the given data and that it is easy to plot works well naturally well with zero, one way to show the plot is to do what you have done above and edit the labels. Use `get_xticklables()` and `set_xticklables()` after adding 1 to the axis. See if this works. Code below..

```
weights_df = pd.read_excel('myinput.xlsx', 'Sheet56')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.barh(weights_df['Variable'],weights_df['Odds Ratio'] - 1, color="Purple", align='edge', label='Odds Ratio')
labels = ax1.get_xticks().tolist() ## Get the x-axis labels
labels = [x + 1 for x in labels]   ## Add 1 to each label
ax1.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks().tolist())
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)  ## Set the x-axis labels to new values

plt.xlabel('Odds Ratio')
plt.ylabel('Variable')
plt.title("Odds Ratios")
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]